# Passing DataReader from Method to .cs page - use CommandBehavior.CloseConnection but connection not closing

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection, datareader, application-pool

I use the following method in a class - which I call from .cs page filling a datareader:

```
public static SqlDataReader getinfo(string username, string url)
{
    //Initialise connection, string stored in Web.config
    SqlConnection conNs = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conNs"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmdNs = new SqlCommand("usp_getinfo", conNs);
    cmdNs.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmdNs.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmdNs.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;
    cmdNs.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@url", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmdNs.Parameters["@url"].Value = url;

    //Execute Command
    conNs.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmdNs.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    //Return data
    return dr;
}
```

Notice 'commendbehavior.closeconnection'.

Then in a .cs page I call it like this:

```
SqlDataReader drInfo = dataAccess.getinfo(username, url);
//do some stuff
drInfo.Close();
```

That should close the connection too no?

I am having a problem with the apppool filling up with open connections. Is there a problem with my technique?

Speed is my priority here.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend passing around references to a data reader... what you should do in my opinion is have a method query the database and turn the results into a single result object (or a collection of result objects) from that data reader; e.g. read the values from the datareader into objects and return those objects (instead of passing around the data reader reference)

Comment: Thanks for your input - many would agree with you - my priority is speed however. Any idea why the connection isn't closing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return a datatable instead of SQLDataReader and you need to close the connection right after you finish reading from the data reader.

Comment: I would like to use a datareader as it is the fastest option?

should my CommandBehavior.CloseConnection - not be closing the connection here? Appears it's not for some reason.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the connection isn't kept open in the connection pool or is the count always increasing?

Comment: the count increases until 100 - at which point you get a timeout exception.

definitely seems like the dr.close() isn't closing the connection

Comment: Perhaps it's the command that is holding on to the connection (you don't explicitly release it), what happens if you put the 'cmdNs' in an using block?
    using (SqlCommand cmdNs = new SqlCommand("usp_getinfo", conNs))
    {
        // return dr here
    }

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like GetInfo returns a lot of data. You're better off not passing a DataReader around like this. Inside GetInfo, perform your Read and return an object that contains the information instead of returning the DataReader. The difference in speed will be inconsequential, and you will eliminate all the pain you're going through.